# status 422 Rails 6 uploading images works locally but not in production server amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rails-activestorage

Uploading images to amazon s3 works locally but when I try to upload an image via railway.app, I get a mysterious 422 error. I've set the correct permissions on my bucket.

I have tried two ways of uploading images and both resorted to these errors.

The error arises when I try to attach the image to a record and save it.

Another time is when I try to create a blob.

```
    blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(filename: blob_args[:filename],
                                                        byte_size: blob_args[:byte_size], 
                                                        checksum: blob_args[:checksum], 
                                                        content_type: blob_args[:content_type])
```

I have no idea.

EDIT:

I have no validations on this record.

EDIT:

I am hitting this controller to create a blob, ultimately sending my a signed_id to my front end

```rb
class DirectUploadsController < ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(filename: blob_args[:filename],
                                                            byte_size: blob_args[:byte_size], 
                                                            checksum: blob_args[:checksum], 
                                                            content_type: blob_args[:content_type])
    render json: direct_upload_json(blob)
  end

  private

  def direct_upload_json(blob)
    blob.as_json(root: false, methods: :signed_id).merge(service_url: url_for(blob)).merge(direct_upload: {
                                                                                             url: blob.service_url_for_direct_upload,
                                                                                             headers: blob.service_headers_for_direct_upload
                                                                                           })
  end
end
```

My FE is sending an image to my Rails API. This works locally, it even gets uploaded into a bucket but when I do this in a remote server, creating a blob or attaching an image to a record resorts to a status 422 log from my FE.

Here is the FE Code, this is in Angular2.

```js
  uploadFile = (name:any, the_attachment:any) => { // name is a string, the_attachment is a File object

    const upload = new DirectUpload(
      the_attachment,
      'https://some-api.railway.app/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads', // This url is exposed by default in your app
    );
    upload.create((error, blob) => {
      if (error) {
        // debugger
        console.log(error)
        // Something happened, handle the error
      } else {
        // blob.signed_id, a String, is the key piece of data that lets Rails identify the file we are referring to
        let signed_id = blob.signed_id;
        // debugger

        // BONUS: We can already request the uploaded file from Rails by using this url.
        // let url = `/rails/active_storage/blobs/${signed_id}/${"whatever_we_want_the_filename_to_be"}`;
        let request_body = {
          logo: signed_id
        }
        // post_thing_to_rails(request_body) // This can be REST, or GraphQL, doesn't matter

        this.http.put("https://some-api.railway.app/api/v1/upload_logo/38", request_body).subscribe((resp)=>{
          console.log(resp)
        })
      }
    });
```

AWS CORS Policy JSON

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://some-app.up.railway.app/",
            "https://some-admin.netlify.app/",
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

```
POST https://some-app.up.railway.app/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads 422
q @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543sdfsdfc43c26d.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a54sdfs3c43c26d.js:1
scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
Me @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
o.<computed> @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
value @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
value @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.95931asdf543c43c26d.js:1
runTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.959sdf31a543c43c26d.js:1
Z @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
N @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
B @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
load (async)
J.t @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
scheduleEventTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
i.<computed>.Y.<computed>.<computed> @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
value @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
value @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
value @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
uploadFile @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
onSubmit @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
km @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
i @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
next @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
_next @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
next @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
$r @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
next @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
emit @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
onSubmit @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
km @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
i @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
runTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
Z @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
N @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26d.js:1
B @ polyfills.95931a543c43c26sdfsdfd.js:1
Show 27 more frames
main.a7200f0b44d7afc6.js:1 Error creating Blob for "386-3863556_ruby-clipart-vector-ruby-programming-language-png-transparent.png". Status: 422
```

Comment: You need to show how you are uploading, i.e. code examples. Also have you examined the headers for the 422 error? This question is far too thin. You need to give us a lot more info.

Comment: @Beartech How would I go about examining the headers? I don't have too much info other than "Error creating Blob for "305797023_2000837373448880_600233784531497375_n.jpeg". Status: 422"

Comment: Thanks for adding all the info, very helpful.  When I've had problems with S3 like this it's almost always been some sort of CORS issue. Is the domain of your dev server different than that of your production server? You can look at the console of your web browser by right-clicking on the page and choosing "inspect element", then in the developer's console choose the tab marked "console". Then try to the upload again. It should have more detail about the error. You can also examine things like headers in the other tabs of the console.

Comment: @Beartech I went ahead and updated the comment there. I see I will dig deep. It's probably something super simple I'm not seeing.

Comment: Can you add the console logs from your remote web server? This should tell you more about why it's failing.

Comment: @Beartech From the logs it gives 

2022-09-15 04:59:45 +0000 HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>

Comment: @Beartech So I went ahead and used heroku and it worked. So it's something with railway.app that's going on.